# SQL Insert into select with multiple select queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables:

- `[PriceTagSticker]`
- `[ClientPriceTagSticker]`

`ClientPriceTagSticker` has a foreign key to `PriceTagSticker`.

I need to backfill some data in the ClientPriceTagSticker table. The goal is for each ClientId in ClientPriceTagSticker, to insert all PriceTagStickerId's that don't already exist.

I have written the query for a single ClientId which works great.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ClientPricetagSticker] (ClientId, PricetagStickerId)
    SELECT 
        @clientId, PS.PriceTagStickerId 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[PricetagSticker] PS
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ClientPricetagSticker]
                   WHERE PriceTagStickerId = PS.PriceTagStickerId 
                     AND ClientId = @clientId)
```

However, I need to do this for all ClientId's in the database, which is the result of this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ClientId 
FROM [dbo].[ClientPricetagSticker]
```

My non-SQL brain initially thought of iterating over the result and executing the single ClientId code using a CURSOR. However - I have been told that cursor's should be avoiding due to performance issues.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this without using a cursor?

Comment: I am sure replacing client id will work like below  `INSERT INTO [dbo].[ClientPricetagSticker] (ClientId, PricetagStickerId)
SELECT ps.clientid, PS.PriceTagStickerId FROM [dbo].[PricetagSticker] PS
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ClientPricetagSticker] cs
    WHERE cs.PriceTagStickerId = PS.PriceTagStickerId AND ClientId = ps.clientid=cs.clientid
)`

Comment: ClientId only lives on ClientPriceTagSticker , so:
SELECT ps.clientid
does not resolve :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cross join` to generate all the rows.  Then remove the rows that exist:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ClientPricetagSticker] (ClientId, PricetagStickerId)
    SELECT c.clientId, PS.PriceTagStickerId
    FROM [dbo].[PricetagSticker] ps CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT DISTINCT ClientId FROM [dbo].[ClientPricetagSticker]) c
         dbo.ClientPricetagSticker cpts
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM dbo.ClientPricetagSticker cpts
                      WHERE cpts.PriceTagStickerId = PS.PriceTagStickerId AND
                            cpts.ClientId = c.clientId
                     );
```

This uses the clients in the `ClientPricetagSticker` table.  I would guess that you have another table with all the clients, and you can use that instead.

Comment: Looks like it worked after removing the "dbo.ClientPricetagSticker cpts" line

Comment: Thanks! You are correct, there is a client table - however it is in a different database :)